# How to fix External Control of File Name or Path when using XmlReader.Create(....)

Tags: c#, xmlreader, veracode

When doing `Veracode` scanning of the C# file, the the line #4 fails validations:

```
1. strXML.Append("</root>");
2. XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
3. settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
4. XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXML.ToString(), settings);
5. xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

What's the possible solution to that?

Comment: Maybe the answer here is of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938048/what-is-the-best-way-to-fix-improper-restriction-of-xml-external-entity-referen

Comment: Thx. This is it